# Challenge in Fabric crashanalytics setup in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, google-fabric

I was able to successfully Install plugins of FAbric by using two commands below :

**$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=XXX --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=xxx**

**$ npm install --save @ionic-native/fabric**

Then I added below lines in my app.component.ts file :

import { Crashlytics } from '@ionic-native/fabric';

this.crashlytics.addLog("Error while loading data");

**I could see crodova-fabric-plugin installed in my plugin folder and still I am getting below error in my console when I test my APK file in the device :**

vendor.js:83771 Native: tried calling Crashlytics.addLog, but the Crashlytics plugin is not installed.pluginWarn @ vendor.js:83771

vendor.js:83783 Install the Crashlytics  plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin'pluginWarn @ vendor.js:83783

vendor.js:83771 Native: tried calling Crashlytics.sendCrash, but the Crashlytics plugin is not installed.pluginWarn @ vendor.js:83771

vendor.js:83783 Install the Crashlytics  plugin: 'ionic Cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin'

Also, I am not able to see anything in my fabric account. Please let me know what is the miss I am doing from my side.

Comment: did you add 'Crashlytics' as providers to the app.module?

Comment: Yes I did add it as provider.

Comment: Got it to work?
Seems difficult to implement in Ionic nowadays (that it's not fabric anymore)